# Django 1.5 url deprecation warning causes 500 error in Webfaction Apache wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-1.5

I've updated this particular app from Django 1.4 to Django 1.5 and everything's worked fine locally - I had to fix some `url` calls, but that was fine.Now while deploying to Webfaction and running the site through Apache + mod_wsgi I'm getting error 500s on every page I try and load.

All the config files have remained the same, only the Django libraries have changed. I've pip installed all the requirements and they load fine.

If I turn the site down to debug mode with `DEBUG = True` in my local settings, then everything works fine. On the error log while in debug mode, I get the following:

```
[Sun Mar 24 22:47:17 2013] [error] /home/user/webapps/app/htdocs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/defaults.py:3: DeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
[Sun Mar 24 22:47:17 2013] [error]   DeprecationWarning)
```

My question is - why is this being raised as an error? `[error]`? Shouldn't it be at the `[info]` level? And could this be what's causing the 500 errors when I take the app out of debug mode?

What can I do to get the site alive again with Django 1.5? Is there a way to turn off these warnings?

I did have a look at this commit in the Django source https://github.com/django/django/commit/0d49fdb573d44794cc78c6af4761cc79c5330315 and see if I could turn off the logging in my app's local_settings file, but no luck.

This is my `httpd.conf` file:

```
ServerRoot "/home/user/webapps/app/apache2"

LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/user/logs/user/access_app.log combined
ErrorLog /home/user/logs/user/error_app.log
LogLevel info
KeepAlive Off
Listen 27114
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 5
WSGIDaemonProcess app processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/user/lib/python2.7:/home/user/webapps/app/htdocs:/home/user/webapps/app/htdocs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup app
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/webapps/app/htdocs/ag/wsgi.py
```

This is my `wsgi.py`

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ag.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution - the `[error]` messages were a red herring.

In Django 1.5, when `DEBUG = False` in settings, then `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is **required** in the settings file. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#allowed-hosts-required-in-production

Otherwise the site will raise 500 errors - which is what I was getting.

Add the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and everything's back to normal again. Simple case of RTFM.

Comment: If this is correct answer for your question, Mark it as accepted answer ;)

Comment: thanks @HuckleberryFinn - I didn't think of that. It says I can accept my own answer in 6 hours.

Comment: The question remains, why do we get the deprecation warnings with the latest django (currently 1.5)? Is that a bug/slipped update from the django side?

Comment: @shailenTJ Latest Django is 1.5.2 right? I haven't used Django since I posted this question.

Comment: That is correct! I am using Django 1.5.2 and I get this warning. It is not nice to see warnings in the logs :(

Comment: @shailenTJ Memory is that you just add your server to allowed hosts and those warnings go away. In version 1.5 I was blocked because this didn't warn, it raised an exception.

Comment: @jamesc: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I am still in debug mode, and I wanted to get rid of the warning because it messes with other print statements I have in my code to trace stuff. I guess it is a bug in the latest Django.